# commitscripts to svn repository in ubuntu

Tags: svn, ubuntu

I'm new to Ubuntu, I have library at svn repository and I  also know user name and password,how to get that library into my local system.
I have done like the following.
sudo apt-get install subversion
sudo svn --username  --password  co https://svn.datadrivensafety.com:3690/

I got the them inside \Dharani folder inside this,i am writing the scripts in
\Dharani\truck\sources\sample.rb
now I want to add and commit those files to svn repository

Could anybody help me I’m wondering.For any help Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The first time you checkout the project you want to work on (`svn co ...`)

From then onwards, your daily workflow is more less like:

- Update changes from your other team members (if any) with `svn update`
- If you created or copied new files which need to be versioned: `svn add folder/myfile.rb`
- Check your changes before sending them back to the server with `svn status`
- Commit your changes: `svn commit`

This is explained in great detail in the SVN Book which is free (http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) and the [basic workflow is explained here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.tour.cycle.html).

You'll probably like to use a desktop tool such as [RabbitVCS](http://www.rabbitvcs.org/) which is integrated on the file explorer (much like TortoiseSVN on Windows).

Comment: could you please clarify me what is working copy I'm getting svn '.'is not a working copy.

Comment: A working copy is your local copy of the code you just downloaded. The error means that the current directory you're looking at does not contain the project you downloaded from svn, but probably a subfolder of it. Try downloading your project with: "svn --username xxx --password co https://svn.datadrivensafety.com:3690/ myproject". This will create a new directory "myproject". Change to that directory with "cd myproject" and you will be able to run the svn commands.